# Free video (screencast , webcasts ...) training on DDD

Tags: c#, .net, domain-driven-design

Are there any free video training resources for Domain Driven Design ?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

There are some great DDD resources in this [Geeks with Blogs post](https://web.archive.org/web/20161130014922/http://geekswithblogs.net:80/Podwysocki/archive/2007/12/28/118036.aspx).

This [SO post on DDD readings](https://web.archive.org/web/20111101003134/http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1353742/domain-driven-design-ddd-readings) is packed full of good stuff too.

Kindness,

Dan

Answer (score 2):

http://dddcommunity.org/ has a few presentations available online, not straight "training" per se, but some good content available; more so with PDF and writeups.

[InfoQ](http://www.infoq.com/) has a lot from Eric Evans himself, but I believe some content you need to be a member for.

Answer (score 2):

[**Best Tech Videos**](http://www.bestechvideos.com/) is a user driven social content website dedicated to finding the best educational videos for developers. You can search there for DDD tagged videos. It is a great resource center to learn if you can't afford attend all the valuable IT conferences and events. The url is http://www.bestechvideos.com/